What base case is correct for this strong-induction chocolate-bar problem?
Problem.  Prove by induction that an $n\times m$ chocolate bar can be broken completely into squares using $nm - 1$ row or column breaks.
This proof uses the base case of a chocolate bar $1 \times 1$.  Their induction is on the number of rows.  I think their base case should have been $1 \times m$ and not $1 \times 1$ because their induction is on $n$.  It is easy to prove that a bar of dimensions $1 \times m$ takes only $m - 1$ breaks, satisfying the formula $nm - 1$ when $n = 1$.  Am I completely mistaken here or do they have this small correction to make?

You misunderstood the proof. They don't induct on rows only, they say "WLOG we may assume the first break is along a row" (because the other case works the exact same way by symmetry).

Note that the problem isn't posed optimally (either here or on the linked site). The best statement is that it takes exactly $mn-1$ breaks regardless of the strategy one chooses. (Induction is certainly a fine way of proving this, but also … count the number of pieces after each break.)
